NS_ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED ошибка reverse proxy nginx localhost
Мой nginx запущен в контейнере (docker compose), его внешний порт 8083, а внутренний 8088.
И я пытаюсь обратиться от сервисного nginx (установлен через apt-get) к докер-изображению nginx
Если я выставляю
proxy_pass http://example.com:8083/
все в порядке, но когда я запрашиваю страницу по https https://example.com:8083/, я получаю ошибку mixed content. Я также думаю, что это плохая практика и хотел бы использовать localhost.
Но если я устанавливаю proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8083, firefox выдает мне ошибку NS_ERROR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Хотя я могу успешно получить, например, стили через curl http://127.0.0.1:8083/style.css.
GET-запрос идет не на example.com, а на 127.0.0.1:8083. Не знаю, нормально ли это. Где нарисовано - example.com.
Ошибка в firefox
docker-compose.yml (nginx (service) image)
nginx:
    image: nginx:1.25
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
      - ./.docker-compose/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    ports:
      - ${EXTERNAL_WEB_PORT:-8083}:8088
    networks:
      - client
    depends_on:
      - app

nginx (service)
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8083/;
    }
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name example.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8083/;
        }
}

